# How to filter Yahoo Finance data by Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get data from Yahoo Finance. I use beautiful soup. I want to get sector(s) and industry information. However, the result is not impressive, it output a lot of unneccessary data. I just want to get:

Sector(s): Healthcare
Industry: Drug Manufacturers—General
Full Time Employees: 11,800

Here is the code:

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILD/profile?p=GILD"
with req.urlopen(url) as response:
data = response.read().decode("utf-8")

import bs4
root = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
titles = root.find_all("span")
```

the result is as attached pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF1k3.png)

Comment: Try using the yahoo module instead: https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/

Answer (score 1):

I would to it this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GILD/profile?p=GILD"

req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')
for p in (soup.select("p.D\(ib\).Va\(t\)")):
        print(p.text)
```

or even simpler:

```
soup.select_one('p.D(ib).Va(t)').text
```

Output:

```
Sector(s): HealthcareIndustry: Drug Manufacturers—GeneralFull Time Employees: 11,800
```

Comment: It returns an error, may I know how to fix it?

SelectorSyntaxError: Invalid character '(' position 3
  line 1:
p.D(ib).Va(t)

Comment: @Janicewww No idea why that should happen. Try using `"` instead of `'` in the `select()` methods and see if that helps.

Comment: @JackFleeting I've updated the code to handle the error. It was because of the parenthesis in the tag.

Comment: Yes it does work after the edit. The changes I made to your code are still pending approval.